# Flutter firebase signInWithPhoneNumber is not defined for a class FirebaseAuth

Tags: flutter

//Here is my main.dart code

```
  signIn() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode)
        .then((user) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

//Here is my pubspec.yaml code

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth:
```

//Here is my logcat

```
 Error: The method 'signInWithPhoneNumber' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'signInWithPhoneNumber'.
```

I am implementing phone number login in my flutter app.I installed all the dependencies and also i pasted google_services.json file in my project.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27486

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I believe you added a wrong reference a comment would be helpful rather than just posting a link

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same issue. I believe its been replaced:

```
final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
  verificationId: _verificationId,
  smsCode: _smsController.text,
);
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/signin_page.dart#L423-L427

Answer (score 4):

Flutter developers has developed their classes and objects for phone authentication into Firebase. So now the way is to verify the verificationId and smsId is:

```
final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
  verificationId: verificationId,
  smsCode: smsCode,
);

FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final FirebaseUser user =
    await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DashboardPage(uid: user.user.uid)),
  );
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
```